# Moving image on canvas on the X axis only

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**The Problem**

I am finding it rather difficult to get my head around this, I am attempting to move an image using the mouse along the X axis only. I am finding it hard to even move the image at all and the many tutorials I have looked at arnt really helping me. Here is what I am trying to say:

[image]

As you can see by my beautiful image above I only want to image to move left and right at the bottom of the page.

**The Code and the Question**

Here is my first attempt, when I try this all the images loaded on the canvas no longer appear making it very hard for me to understand why it isnt working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Referencing the canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var width = canvas.getAttribute('width');
    var height = canvas.getAttribute('height');

    //Images
    var bggameImage = new Image();
    var playerImage = new Image();
    var enemyImage = new Image();
    var projectileImage = new Image();
    var livesImage = new Image();

    //Canvas dimensions
    var width = 480;
    var height = 320;

    //Loading in the backgroundImage
    bggameImage.src = "Images/bggameImage.png";
    bggameImage.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(bggameImage, 0, 0);
    }

    //Loading in the playerImage
    playerImage.src = "Images/playerImage.png";
    playerImage.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(playerImage, 165, 240);
    }

    //Loading in the projectileImage
    projectileImage.src = "Images/projectileImage.png";
    projectileImage.onload = function(){
        context.drawImage(projectileImage, 65, 240);
    }

    var playerImage = {
            x:176,
            y:74,
    }

    function init() {

        playerImage.src = "Images/playerImage.png";

        //Moving player
        myCanvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            var bounding_box = myCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();
            playerImage = (e.clientX - bounding_box.left) * (myCanvas.width / bounding_box.width) - playerImage.width / 2;
            playerImage = (e.clientY - bounding_box.top) * (myCanvas.height / bounding_box.height) - playerImage.height / 2;
        }       
    )
</script>
```

The whole "function init()" part is what I have just tried but I thought I would include this anyway, I understand that I am loading in the playerImage twice.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same variable name twice (playerImage), so your image is being overwritten. You're using it for the image and also to store the position. Change the playerImage that's storing x and y to be playerPosition or something like that. Update that variable on your mouse event and then render the image according to that variable's values.

Ultimately, you're going to have to look at a game loop using setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame. So, this will become crucial at that stage. And yes, you shouldn't be loading the player image twice either. Do all of that at the start and only start your game when all your assets have successfully loaded.

For instance...

```
        var playerImage;
        var alienImage;
        var bulletImage;
        var assetCount = 0;

        function loadAssets() {
            playerImage = new Image();
            playerImage.onload = checkAssetsLoaded;
            playerImage.src = "assets/images/Brush01.png";

            alienImage = new Image();
            alienImage.onload = checkAssetsLoaded;
            alienImage.src = "assets/images/Brush02.png";

            bulletImage = new Image();
            bulletImage.onload = checkAssetsLoaded;
            bulletImage.src = "assets/images/Brush03.png";
        }

        function checkAssetsLoaded(event) {
            assetCount++;
            console.log("An asset has loaded!: " + assetCount);
            if (assetCount == 3) {
                startGame();
            }
        }

        function startGame() {
            // Start your game initialization logic here.
            console.log("Game starting!");
        }
```

Comment: I have changed the 'var playerImage' to 'var playerPosition'. As I am loading the image twice, which do you believe i should keep, the first one or the one inside the 'function init'?

Comment: You could call a function that creates the Image objects you require, sets their onLoad event handler, then sets their source. Inside the event handler for the image loads would be something that changes a state, even just a counter and once you reach the expected count of images to load, then you call your game start function (once all the expected assets have loaded). Don't draw the images on the load event. I'd simply store that they have loaded and then start your game. Your game loop should then handle the update of state and the drawing of that state representation to the canvas.

Comment: So create a function that creates the images, sets their source but doesnt load them, that happened inside the function init in my case?

Comment: Have a function called say loadAssets(). Call that on the load of your document. Then inside that function, for each Image. `var image1 = new Image(); image1.onload = checkAssetsLoaded; image1.src = "path/to/image";` So every image loads and calls checkAssetsLoaded. That function then updates a counter or stores each image loaded as a boolean or something. Then only once all your assets have fully loaded, do you then call your function that starts your game (startGame or something like that). That way, you can be sure that you can use your image variables in your game without issues.

Comment: You could also just have the images you require as <img> tags in the body of your document, but hidden, then once the document is loaded, then you would know that the images had been loaded also. Whichever you prefer :)

Comment: I have just made a small js fiddle just to see if this is correct? None of the images are loading onto the canvas https://jsfiddle.net/3oc4jsf6/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107143/discussion-between-rushfan2112-and-manodestra).

Comment: I've added some code to my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: Moving the code that you provided above, as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/3oc4jsf6/2/ Surely it should atleast be showing the images on the canvas now? no?

Comment: Not until you draw them there, no. This is simply about preloading the images for use. Once they're loaded, then you can draw them to the canvas in the draw() method of your game loop e.g. `function gameLoop() { update(); draw(); setTimeout(gameLoop, 50); }` For every tick of the game loop, you are going to draw your images on the canvas' 2d context.